# How to return a value ($row['value']) from a mySQL dB within an editable text field, so that the value can be changed and the dB UPDATED

Tags: php, html, mysql, dom

/* At the moment a blank input/text field is displayed followed by the $row['value'].  */

<

```
?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    print("<form method= 'post' action= ''>");
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++) {
        if ($x == 0) {
            print("<tr>");
        } else {
            print("<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>" . "<td><input  type = 'hidden' name= 'input'  value=>".$row['value']."</input></td>" . "<td>" . $row['color'] . "</td>"."<td><a name = 'ID' href='updatePoll.php?ID=".$row['name']."'>Update</a></td>");
            $x++;
            if ($x == 1) {
                print "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
print("</form>");




}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Try: `<input  type = 'hidden' name= 'input'  value='" . $row['value'] . ">' to display the value. I guess that your form points to a page that will update the value in the database?

Comment: This `value=>` is a typo.

Comment: fix ^^ typo and then remove the anchor tag and then add hidden field to hold the ID and then add submit button ___i.e. A total rewrite___

Answer (score -1):

In your code there is problem on following line at value=>".$row['value']."

```
print("<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>" . "<td><input  type = 'hidden' name= 'input'  value=>".$row['value']."</input></td>" . "<td>" . $row['color'] . "</td>"."<td><a name = 'ID' href='updatePoll.php?ID=".$row['name']."'>Update</a></td>");
```

Replace above with following.

```
print("<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>" . "<td><input  type = 'hidden' name= 'input'  value='".$row['value']."' ></td>" . "<td>" . $row['color'] . "</td>"."<td><a name = 'ID' href='updatePoll.php?ID=".$row['name']."'>Update</a></td>");
```